# How I can prove Ramsey number R(2,3,4) > 8?

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I need to prove $R(2,3,4) > 8$ with Ramsey theory. How can I do that?

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/Ramsey43.shtml

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You can't have any edges of color $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Can you prove $R(3,4) \gt 8$ ?

Comment: @rschwieb This is not a new question. It is, indeed, an answer to the original question.

Comment: @all Sorry, I mistook this as an out of place question. My bad!